# How can I read and identify error popup notifications?

Tags: gnome, notification

Errors appear in a notification window below the clock in Ubuntu 22 (with Gnome).  They appear for about one second, then vanish.  The text in them is too long to fit in the notification window.  Mousing over the window and clicking reveals more of the message (if you're very quick with the mouse) but it does not keep the window around, so I still can't read it.  The text of the notification does not appear in the list of notifications if I click on the clock.  There is no text at the start of the error message to indicate which process or application is posting it.  There might be some later, but I can't ever read it.

My questions are general:

1. What is the method for dealing with errors that are presented like this?
2. Are they logged somewhere else?
3. Is there a way of revealing a history of them or getting them to stay around for longer?

Note that there is nothing relevant in /var/log/syslog or dmesg.